# When is a group homomorphism “extendable”?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, definition

$\newcommand{iotaLift}{\iota\!\uparrow\!(S, H)}$
Say we have finite groups $S\leq G$ and $H$. If we have a homomorphism $\phi\colon S\to H$, it does not always have to be the case that we find a homomorphism from $G\to H$ that agrees with $\phi$ on $S$. For instance, the identity homomorphism $G \geq S\to S$ cannot be extended if (surjective) homomorphisms $G\to S$ don't even *exist* at all.  This happens for instance if there is no $N\lhd G$ such that $S \simeq G/N$.

**Definition** Let $S, G, H$ be finite groups, $\iota\colon S\to G$ a monomorphism (that is, an injective group homomorphism). Define $$
\iotaLift := \{\phi\colon S\to H \mid \exists \overline\phi\colon G\to H: \overline\phi\circ \iota = \phi\}
$$
to be the set of all such extendable homomorphisms.

> - For which $H$ is $\iotaLift$ trivial (contains only the zero homomorphism)?
> - For which $H$ is $\iotaLift = \operatorname{Hom}_{\underline{\operatorname{Grp}}}(S, H)$?
> - Does this set have any obvious algebraic structure, e.g. a partial order, or an algebraic operation that constructs new extendable functions from old ones?
> - Does the *complement* of this set?

*(I know that the last two points are rather open-ended, and hope this is still acceptable for M.SE.)*

#### Examples

- Assume the injection $\iota$ “splits”, i.e., admits an inverse $\sigma: \sigma\circ\iota = \operatorname{id}_S$. Then every $\phi$ can be extended to $\phi\circ\sigma$, which indeed satisfies $\phi\circ\sigma\circ\iota=\phi$. So $\iotaLift = \operatorname{Hom}_{\underline{\operatorname{Grp}}}(S, H)$.
- Similar to the case mentioned above, Let $G$ be simple, $S$ any subgroup, and $H$ a group such that $G$ does not embed into $H$. Therefore, the only homomorphisms $G\to H$ must be trivial, and so is every restriction onto $S$. Ergo, $\iotaLift=\{(s\mapsto 1)\}$.
- Consider the (only nontrivial) embedding $C_2\to C_4$ with arbitrary $H$.  Since morphisms $C_n\to H$ correspond with elements $h\in H$ of order dividing $n$, extendable morphisms $C_2\to H$ correspond to elements who have a square root (including the identity).
- If we have an extendable function, we can compose it with any element of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ that is not trivial on its image to obtain a new function, whose extandability is easily checked.

Comment: The last sentence in your first paragraph is wrong. Take $S=Z_2$ as subgroup of the symmetric group $S_3$ in $G = S_3\times Z_2$.

Comment: @j.p. that concerns only the “any only if” part, correct?

Comment: Yes, as the kernel $N$ of the extended identity (assuming such an extension exists) has the property $S\simeq G/N$.

Comment: @j.p. thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: Wait, so $\iota$ can be any monomorphism? Not just the inclusion map? And is $\iota$ fixed for all four of those questions?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 $\iota$ is fixed. the reason I introduce $\iota$ is because in the definition (i.e., after the introductory rambling), I never required $S$ to be a subgroup of $G$ – it's a matter of taste, I prefer to see subobjects as monomorphisms. I could have equivalently said “Let $S\leq G$ and $\iota\colon S\to G$ the corresponding inclusion map”.